# How to create the User Name and then Insert/relate data with User using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here is the code in Java I am trying to create the user then insert data in Firebase for a single user.
What can I do to insert data for a single user?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button submit;
    EditText text1;
    FirebaseDatabase mydata;
    DatabaseReference mref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);

        mydata = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mref = mydata.getReference();

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data = text1.getText().toString();
                mref.setValue(data);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

At first create a new class as below to handle things easier .

```
public class User {
public String phone, address;

public User() {

}

public User(String phone, String address) {
    this.phone = phone;
    this.address = address;
}}
```

Then edit your posted code .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button submit;
//EditText text1;
// FirebaseDatabase mydata;
//  DatabaseReference mref;
private EditText nameEdit, phoneNumberEdit, addressEdit;
public String name, phoneNumber, address;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    // text1 = findViewById(R.id.text1);
    nameEdit = findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
    phoneNumberEdit = findViewById(R.id.phonenumberEdit);
    addressEdit = findViewById(R.id.addressEdit);

    // mydata = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    // mref = mydata.getReference();

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  String data = text1.getText().toString();
            //  mref.setValue(data);
            name = nameEdit.getText().toString().trim();
            phoneNumber = phoneNumberEdit.getText().toString();
            address = addressEdit.getText().toString().trim();
            User user = new User(
                    phoneNumber,
                    address
            );
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(name)
                    .setValue(user);
            //  mref.setValue(user);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

will get data as below format.
[image]

You can edit User class to get your desire format.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to users, the best option that you have is to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth). Once you have the authentication mechanism implemented, you'll be able to distinguish the users by their unique UIDs. This means that you can create a separate location in the database for each and every user. While @ZahidIslam's solution will work, storing the name of the user as a key in the database, might not sound like the best solution, because each node in Firebase Realtime Database can be considered a Map, a data structure that doesn't allow duplicates. So if another user with the same "zahid" name joins your app, the data will be overwritten, and I think that this is not what you want.

So considering having a POJO class for your users, with a minimum declaration that looks like this:

```
class User {
    String uid, name;
}
```

To save the user data, simply use the following lines of code in Java:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
usersRef.child(uid).setValue(new User(uid, "Hamid Idrees")).addOnCompleteListener(/* ... /*);
```

The result in the Firebase Console will be:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
        |
        --- $uid
             |
             --- uid: "uidThatComesFromFirebaseUserObject"
             |
             --- name: "Hamid Idrees"
```